# Python in VSCode - PIP Error (cmd not found)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-import

Help Me! I'm new! I've been **using Python Idle for learning basics** but decided to **switch to VSCode** as a Harvard Professor advised in his tutorial for convenience.

Q. **Trying to Import** the Basic *Cowsay module* using **PIP** (cmd in VSC Terminal: pip install cowsay), getting an **ERROR** (bash: pip: cmd not found). What am I doing wrong?

Installed Python Extensions in VSCode
Tried creating a New File - X
Tried installing the module directly - X
Still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install PIP seperately.

First you need to download the file get-pip.py for open up terminal or command prompt and then run the below command:

```bash
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

After that, based on your Operating system you can try the below:

Linux & Mac:

```bash
python get-pip.py
```

Windows:

```bash
py get-pip.py
```

Comment: When I write (python get-pip.py) in VSC terminal I get (bash: get_pip.py: command not found).
Have I missed a step to setup VSC?

Comment: Just open up the terminal or command prompt then run this command first to download the get-pip.py file: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
Once the file is downloaded the run the already given command: `python get-pip.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manual installation by visiting to [pip manual installation](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py); download the script, then navigate to the folder having that script `cd your_folderName` and run

`python get-pip.py`

Comment: So, I checked the official page to see whether I already have it or not. 

'code python3 -m pip --version'
>>> 'pip 24.0 from /Lib....../Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)'
'code python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel'
>>> Requirement already satisfied:...

Do you think you'd be able to import modules or functions?

Answer (score 0):

The correct to install. Released: Mar 16, 2024

```
py - m pip install python-cowsay
```